# Android Studio Emulator Not Working, Immediately Crashing

Tags: android, emulation

last night I was trying to use Android Studio on my "new" computer. I kept getting the "emulator process for AVD Pixel_3a_API_30_x86 was killed" when I tried launching the emulator from the AVD managaer, and when I tried running an app from code, it would just crash immediately and not tell me I got an error (mac os would just notify me that qemu-system-x86_64 quit unexpectedly). Does anyone know how to fix this? I tried following a few videos but nothing worked. Even updating the SKD Build-Tools 31-rc1 to 31.0.0 rc1 didn't work. I have HAXM which is what a lot of "fixes" suggest but still doesn't work. No matter which system image I pick, it always crashes! Please help!
[photo 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGhOS.png) [photo 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poNJc.png)
Computer details: mac mini 2011, intel i5 2.3, mac os high sierra, 16gb ram & 480 ssd (storage is not the issue I don't think?).

Comment: Have you checked the Graphics option selected for the avd? Try changing to software mode. and restart AS

Comment: @AdesuyiAyodeji THANK YOU